# jQuery: Count images

Tags: jquery

I have a folder with images named `example_**_title.jpg`.

I want to count these images with jQuery/Javascript and return the number of images.

I tried:

```
count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){
   var bg_url = 'http://www.example-url.com/example_'+i+'_title.jpg';
   $.get(bg_url)
   .done(function(){ 
      count++;
   })
   .fail(function(){
   });
}
alert(count);
```

Thanks for the help.

Jones

Comment: What did you get? Why didn't it work?

Comment: A server side script is such as PHP is optimal for this. Javascript is client side, it technically can't do this unless you're loading all the image like you're doing... wasting bandwidth...

Comment: You have a `'` missing after `'_title.jpg`, it shoule be `'_title.jpg'`

Comment: Could you post the respective PHP-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to `get` the files but just count, you can use `type:'HEAD'` It should reduce the amount of data :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example-url.com/example_'+i+'_title.jpg',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    { 
      //file doesn't exist
    },
    success: function()
    {
        count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, this is a quote missing on your code. I hope that is just a typo.

```
count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){
   var bg_url = 'http://www.example-url.com/example_'+i+'_title.jpg';
   $.get(bg_url, function(data){ count++; });
}
alert(count);
```