# Count images in folder and show div with unique id

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and working on a test project for my own.

I want to count all images in a specific folder. For each image found i want to show a div with an unique id and the image. I want to do this all in jQuery without PHP.

The images are numbered between 1 and 100

http://jsfiddle.net/bojba43s/1/

For now i have:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://example.com/images/'+i+'.JPG',
type:'HEAD',
error: function()
{ 
  alert('EMPTY FOLDER');
},
success: function()
{
    count++;
    $('#TARGET').append('<div id="img_div_' + i + '"><img src=" http://example.com/images/' + i + '.JPG"><div>');
}
```

});

and this counts the number of images. But how do i have to show the divs like this?

```
<div id="insert unique id"><img src="insert image"><div>
```

Comment: What is this `i`? From where is it coming?

Comment: Where is `var i;` declaration ? And I think you should use a Php function to count all files in the folder images and send back the number found.

Comment: i'm sorry.   i comes from:  for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){

Comment: @Maxcim _"The images are numbered between 1 and 100"_ Whether request is for one image or one-hundred images , process and results should be the same

Answer (score 1):

You can append them using jQuery in your ajax success block:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com/images/'+i+'.jpg',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    { 
      alert('EMPTY FOLDER');
    },
    success: function()
    {
        count++;
        $('#target').append('<div id="img_div_' + i + '"><img src=" http://example.com/images/' + i + '.jpg"><div>');
    }
});
```

And then just have a "target" element in your html:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Or, append it in a similar way before your ajax call!

Comment: @Maxcim - no problem! If it worked for you please accept it so it might helps someone else out down the line - best, Wah.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but it is not working. I don't know where to find the problem as i don't have enough knowledge to debug it. 

I know have this in the code:

`<script>
$.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com/images/'+i+'.jpg',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    { 
      alert('EMPTY FOLDER');
    },
    success: function()
    {
        count++;
        $('#target').append('<div id="img_div_' + i + '"><img src=" http://example.com/images/' + i + '.jpg"><div>');
    }
});
</script>`

Comment: @Maxcim - you should be able to [create a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something (including the one built into SO!) and post your code. And, inspect the console please to see if there are any errors...

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have made a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bojba43s/1/

Comment: The code is working now, thank you. But if i have 2 images on the server named 1.JPG & 2.JPG the script is creating 2 divs with the same id, id 11 and filenames 11  http://jsfiddle.net/maxcim/bojba43s/3/

Comment: @Maxcim - I can't replicate or see this behavior from the fiddle you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are not going to be able to count all of the images in a folder with javascript. You'll need make a request to the server, which in turn will count the files in the folder and return the response to your ajax method. The response will contain the count which can then be appended to an element of your choosing.

On second inspection and reading the comments I see you're iterating from 1 through to 10 and making requests for each number as the file name. This is assuming all images are jpgs and named from 1 to 10. What happens if a folder has 100000 images? Are you going to make that many requests?

Comment: On this threat i see a solution with a comment that it works. But i can't get it to work on my site.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069760/jquery-count-images

Comment: Are your images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc? I updated my answer by the way.

Comment: there will never more than 10 files

and if there are more than i can cover that with this i thought  i<=10

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"GET"` request to avoid requesting image twice , if exists ; `$.when.apply()` , `$.map()` , `$.Deferred()` , `.always()` , `$.grep()` , `Blob` , `URL.createObjectURL`

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var requests = $.when.apply($, $.map(arr, function(n) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/images/" + n + ".JPG",
    type: "GET"
  })

  request.always(function(data, textStatus) {
    // return file if found , else `false`    
    dfd.resolve(textStatus !== "error" ? data : false)
  })
  return dfd.promise()
}))
requests.always(function() {
  console.log(arguments)
  // filter `false` values in responses
  var res = $.grep(arguments, Boolean);
    if (res.length) {
      res.forEach(function(img) {
        $("div").append(
          $("<img>", {
            id: id,
            // if images exists , append new image element to `div`
            src: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([img])) 
          })[0].outerHTML
        )
      })
    } else {
      $("div").html("no images found");
      console.log(res)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  But what if the amount of images is nog always the same?

Comment: @Maxcim _"But what if the amount of images is nog always the same?"_  Should return same results.

Comment: Thx!   Last question :)    can i also have more control on how to fill the div?  like adding style, other content(text)?  

For example something like this? 
`$('#target').append('<div id="img_div_' + i + '"><img src=" http://example.com/images/' + i + '.jpg"><div>');
    }`

Comment: @Maxcim Yes , can omit additional call to server , load image that was returned by setting `src` to objectURL `$('#target').append('<div id=img_div_' + i + '><img src='+URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([img]))+'><div>');`